# How can I adjust the location of icon and text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: null,
              label: Text("Close"),
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            )
```

[image]

As seen in the picture, the icon is on the left, the text is on the right. How can I do the opposite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap the

```
ElevatedButton.icon
```

with

```
Directionality
```

and make direction rtl

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution, but you can switch `label` and `icon` values.

```
label: Icon(Icons.close),
icon: Text('Close'),
```